# Docker fails to pull the image from within Azure App Service

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

The Container Setting on the App Service it self look solid:
[image]

But the log pane shows errors:

[image]

```
2020-02-11 06:31:40.621 ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2020-02-11 06:31:41.240 INFO  - Stoping site app505-dfpg-qa2-web-eastus2-gateway-apsvc because it failed during startup.
2020-02-11 06:36:05.546 INFO  - Starting container for site
2020-02-11 06:36:05.551 INFO  - docker run -d -p 9621:8081 --name app505-dfpg-qa2-web-eastus2-gateway-apsvc_0_a9c8277e_msiProxy -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=app505-dfpg-qa2-web-eastus2-gateway-apsvc -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=app505-dfpg-qa2-web-eastus2-gateway-apsvc.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=7d18d5957d129d3dc3a25d7a2c85147ef57f1a6b93910c50eb850417ab59dc56 appsvc/msitokenservice:1904260237  

2020-02-11 06:36:05.552 INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2020-02-11 06:36:17.766 INFO  - Pulling image: a...cr/gateway:1.0.20042.2
2020-02-11 06:36:17.922 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"pull access denied for a...cr/gateway, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"}

2020-02-11 06:36:17.923 ERROR - Pulling docker image a...cr/gateway:1.0.20042.2 failed:
2020-02-11 06:36:17.923 INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: a...cr/gateway:1.0.20042.2
2020-02-11 06:36:18.092 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"pull access denied for a...cr/gateway, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"}

2020-02-11 06:36:18.094 ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2020-02-11 06:36:19.062 INFO  - Stoping site app505-dfpg-qa2-web-eastus2-gateway-apsvc because it failed during startup.
```

The Service Principal used to deploy the App Service has AcrPush access to the parent resource group of the container registry:
[image]

The setting are present:

[image]

I did `az login` with that service principal and then tried `az acr login` to the registry. It works fine. So what am I missing here?

**EDIT 1**

I know the credentials are correct, because I tested them like this:
[image]

Where I just copied the values from the app service configuration and pasted on the console. docker has no problem logging in.

It must be something else.

**EDIT 2**

However, I also get this:

```
C:\Dayforce\fintech [shelve/terraform ≡]> docker pull a...r/gateway
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for a...r/gateway, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

So, I can login, but not pull. Very strange, because the account is configured to have `AcrPush` access to the container, which includes `AcrPull`:
[image]

**EDIT 3**

I was able to pull successfully when using the FQDN for the registry:
[image]

I updated the pipeline, but I still get the same errors:

```
2020-02-11 16:03:50.227 ERROR - Pulling docker image a...r.azurecr.io/gateway:1.0.20042.2 failed:
2020-02-11 16:03:50.228 INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: a...r.azurecr.io/gateway:1.0.20042.2
2020-02-11 16:03:50.266 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://a...r.azurecr.io/v2/gateway/manifests/1.0.20042.2: unauthorized: authentication required"}

2020-02-11 16:03:50.269 ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2020-02-11 16:03:50.853 INFO  - Stoping site app505-dfpg-qa2-web-eastus2-gateway-apsvc because it failed during startup.
```

**EDIT 4**

The only way that I found working was to enable the Admin User on the ACR and pass its credentials in the DOCKER_... variables instead of credentials of the Service Principal.

This is frustrating, I know the Service Principal can login and pull when ran locally, it is a mystery why it does not work for docker running on an App Service Host. We have another team here which faced the same issue and they have not found any solution, but enable the Admin User.

**EDIT 5**

The entire process runs as part of the Azure DevOps on-prem release pipeline using a dedicated Service Principal. Let me call it Pod Deploy Service Principal or just **SP** for short.

Let `DOCKER_xyz` denote the three app settings controlling the docker running on the App Service host:

- `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL`
- `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME`
- `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD`

I think we need to distinguish two parts here:

1. App Service needs to talk to the ACR in order to pull from it the details about the image and present them in this GUI - [image] For that to work, the SP must have the AcrPull role in the ACR. Failure to do so results in the GUI presenting a spinning icon for the Image and Tag rows. I stumbled on it before - [How to configure an Azure app service to pull images from an ACR with terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59914397/how-to-configure-an-azure-app-service-to-pull-images-from-an-acr-with-terraform) Now the answer to that question suggests that I have to assign the AcrPull role **and** set the `DOCKER_xyz` app settings. I think that the `DOCKER_xyz` app settings are not for that, but for the second part.
2. It seems to me that when an App Service is started, the host uses docker to actually pull the right image from the ACR. This part seems to be detached from (1). For it to work, the app settings must have the `DOCKER_xyz` app settings.

My problem is that part (1) works great, but part (2) does not even if `DOCKER_xyz` app settings specify the credentials of the SP from part (1). The only way I could make it work if I point `DOCKER_xyz` at the Admin User of the ACR.

But that why on Earth the `DOCKER_xyz` app settings cannot point to the pipeline SP, which was good enough for the part (1)?

**EDIT 6**

The current state of affairs is this. Azure App Service is unable to communicate with an ACR except using ACR admin user and password. So, even if the docker runtime running on the App Service host machine may know how to login using any service principal, the App Service would not use any identity or Service Principal to read metadata from the ACR - only admin user and password. The relevant references are:

- https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/36145444-web-app-for-containers-acr-access-requires-admin#%7btoggle_previous_statuses%7d
- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/49186

On a personal note I find it amazing that Microsoft recommends not to use ACR admin user, yet a very core piece of their offering, namely Azure App Service, depends on it being enable. Makes me wonder whether different teams in Microsoft are aware of what others are doing or not doing...

Comment: It seems your credential is not right. You can try to assign permission directly to the ACR, not the group. And do you enable the admin user?

Comment: How do you deploy the image in ACR? In portal? Or use the Azure CLI with the YAML file or template?

Comment: Please, see **EDIT 4**. That should prove that the image is OK.

Comment: What about your test? Can you share the result?

Comment: @CharlesXu - I did not have time yet.

Comment: Do you still not have time to test? I receive nothing for serial days.

Comment: No, it is on the table and will not go anywhere. But I need to clear first higher priority items. I will get there, no worries.

Comment: So I had this as well, I checked and the credentials Azure automatically put into my app configuration were correct... could NOT get it to work. Changed to a different password (primary to secondary) and it worked fine! All I can think of was that the first password had a + in it... as the error was about input format, and I get similar things in zsh when I have stuff like + characters.

Comment: My app has been working fine for the last few months, but this morning I woke up with this problem, in Production. I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 36):

App service started pulling after doing these steps for me. :D

1. Enable Admin Access in Azure Container Registry
2. In the App service configuration, provide container registry admin credentials
   DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD(admin enabled password),
   DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME(crxxxxxx),
   DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL (https://crxxxxxx.azurecr.io)
3. Go to your app service and select identity section on the left, and click on system assigned - change status to On.
4. Now go to IAM Control container registry, add ACR pull role to App Service system assigned identity enabled on step 3.
5. Restart your App Service and wait .Changes will take few minutes to reflect so refresh your logs. (10 minutes or more)

Good luck :)

Comment: This worked very well for me, thanks @Aswin

Comment: just setting the DOCKER_... variables worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Work for me after configure docker ACR credentials to app service. Thanks

Comment: It worked for me, I don't know if I did something wrong or it was a bug on the Azure side to not fill those envs.

Comment: How do you do step number 4? I can't find that

Comment: @TomBom I also struggled (but wine was involved). Go to your registry first and then add IAM role Acr Pull and next page select radio button Managed Identity

Comment: For this to work for me, I had also to downgrade the docker node version from 18 to 16 and add the node version to my package.json file.

Comment: this worked for me. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

After a lot of research I figured out a way to **resolve this without enabling Admin user**

1. Create an app registration using Azure Active Directory and store the secret somewhere.
2. Go to the Azure container registry and add role assignment to this newly created app with permissions of **AcrPush** (which also contains AcrPull).

[image]
[image]

3. In the App service configuration, replace the variables .

> ```
> DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD with Client Secret of app registration which was saved in the first step
> DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME with client Id of App registration
> ```

This should solve the Docker Api exception.

It's baffling that this is not mentioned in any Azure Container Registry documentation. Although I think it is mentioned somewhere in AAD documentation indirectly .

Comment: Unfortunately, I am out of context now and will not be revisiting the infrastructure for some time. I hope others can validate your findings and upvote accordingly.

Comment: Can verify, this works. (Although I set up with only AcrPull access).
Can't find it documented anywhere.

Depending on how the deployment happens, you might have to add DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL too.

Comment: Just to clarify, in #2, I should add AcrPush role to the Service Principal (subscription) created in #1? I'm not sure if I understand "App Registration" correctly.

Answer (score 5):

From the message I got of the talk, let me solve your puzzle about the error.

I guess you deploy the image in ACR to the Web App through the Azure portal. When you use the Azure portal to deploy the Web App from the ACR, it only lets you select the ACR and image and tag, but do not let you set the credential. In this way, Azure will set it itself with the admin user and password if you enable the admin user. If you do not enable it, the error you got happens.

And if you want to use the service principal, I recommend you use the other tools, such as Azure CLI. Then you can set the docker registry credential yourself with the command [`az webapp config container set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-container-set).

Here is the example and it works fine on my side:

[image]

With the Azure CLI, you can follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image#create-app-service-plan).

**Update:**

Here are the screenshots of the test on my side:

[image]

[image]

Comment: My problem is different. Please, see **EDIT 5**

Comment: I clarified in **EDIT 5** - it denotes the three app settings controlling the docker running on the App Service host:

DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL, 
DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME, 
DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD

Comment: @mark When you say "Failure to do so results in the GUI presenting a spinning icon for the Image and Tag rows", where do you see it? Finish the deployment of the web app and in the container set?

Comment: There is an image in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59914397/how-to-configure-an-azure-app-service-to-pull-images-from-an-acr-with-terraform - In the container settings after the deployment of the App Service is done

Comment: @mark The issue just shows you do not create the service principal to pull the image. If you did, you can see the images in the ACR when the deployment of the web app is finished.

Comment: There was service principal alright, but it did not have the AcrPull role in the ACR. That is why there was the spinning icon. Once AcrPull role was assigned to that service principal, the spinning disappeared and the picture above showed up clearly indicating the image and the tag. That is what I call part (1).

Comment: @mark The service principal with the permission AcrPull is necessary for both part (1) and (2) if you use ACR. It also needs to SP to pull the images. I think if it works for part (1), then it will also work for part (2).

Comment: I totally agree with you. That SP never went away, but your assumption is wrong - it does not work for the part (2) and that is the gist of my SO question. I banged my head on this brick wall for hours before giving up and using ACR Admin User credentials in the part (2). The SP creds just do not work. I welcome you to try for yourself.

Comment: @mark Yeah, I tried myself and it works perfectly. See the update.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Neither my team nor another team we able to make it work with the service principal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207631/discussion-between-charles-xu-and-mark).

Comment: Long time, but I am back - please see **EDIT 6**.

Comment: @mark this is an amazing job from Microsoft (not). Thanks for clarifying, I have exactly the same problem and your information helped.

Comment: Solved setting these environment variables! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer by setting "acrUseManagedIdentityCreds" to True. The second command in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69120462/17430834

Edit 1: Adding the command

Here is the command that you will need to run to make this change.

```
az resource update --ids /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<app-name>/config/web --set properties.acrUseManagedIdentityCreds=True
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30357948)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to mark's amazing job of working it all through and for the fast readers: for everything to work, one of course also has to enable the admin user (who by default is disabled). For example by issuing:

```
az acr update -n <your-azureregistry-name> --admin-enabled true
```

on the console.

Comment: we can achieve this without enabling admin user as well, refer to the answer i have posted

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same from Azure DevOps pipelines and got the same problem.
I didn't find out how to make it work using the ACR name, but it works if you use your_acr_name.azurecr.io instead.
If you go to the Access Keys page of your ACR you will find two values
Registry name: MyCoolRegistry (doesn't work if you use this one)
Login server: mycoolregistry.azurecr.io
The login server is working - just put it as the containerRegistry in your Pipeline without creating a service connection.

Just in case someone is struggling with that one.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this same issue when trying to deploy an Docker application to Azure Web Apps for containers.

When I deployed the application I will get the error below when I checked the **App Services** > **My App Service** > **Deployment Center** > **Container Logs**:

> DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"pull access denied for a..my-repo/image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"}.

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue was that I was not specifying the full path to the image. I was supposed to include `my-registry-url` in the docker `image-name`. That is instead of just `image-name` I was supposed to use `my-registry-url/image-name`, since I am trying to pull from a private repository.

So say these are variables:

- docker image name is `promiseapp`
- docker-registry_url is `promisecicdregistry.azurecr.io`
- resource-group is `dockerprojects`
- app-service-plan is `dockerlinuxprojects`
- azure-web-app name is `promiseapptest`
- docker-registry-user is `test-user`
- docker-registry-password is `12345678`

**CLI**:

My command will be:

```
az webapp create --resource-group dockerprojects --plan dockerlinuxprojects --name promiseapptest --deployment-container-image-name promisecicdregistry.azurecr.io/promiseapp

az webapp config container set --resource-group dockerprojects --name promiseapptest --docker-custom-image-name promisecicdregistry.azurecr.io/promiseapp --docker-registry-server-url https://promisecicdregistry.azurecr.io --docker-registry-server-user test-user --docker-registry-server-password 12345678
```

**Azure Portal**:

To do this on the Azure Portal, simply go to **Azure App Services**, select the **App Service**, go to **Deployment Center**, click on **Settings** and set up the Deployment pipeline.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed the error by using the fully qualified Azure Container Registery name like this:

```
xwezi.azurecr.io
```

The previous value  was

```
xwezi
```

When I deploy manually to App Services, I wouldn't get that error.
But, when I used **Azure App Service deploy** task to deploy the container to the App Service, the service won't work correctly.
And, the log stream will show the above errors.

Unfortunately, the error messages weren't helpful for me to find this out. But I hope this will save your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but in my case I had different tag name in my **Build pipeline** and **Release Pipeline**.

Answer (score 0):

Using only `application_stack` and add `ignore_changes` worked for me.

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app" {
  name                       = "app-${var.PRODUCT}"
  

  site_config {
    
    application_stack {
      docker_image_name        = "my-image:e3920202"
      docker_registry_url      = "https://${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server}"
      docker_registry_username = data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_username
      docker_registry_password = data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_password
    }


  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      app_settings["DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME"],
      site_config[0].application_stack[0].docker_image_name
    ]
  }
}
```

reference:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/16585#issuecomment-1675045540