# Unable to run Azure Web Service from a docker image in an Azure Registry

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, devops

I am trying to automate my deployment process by creating a pipeline in Azure DevOps that does the following

1. Build my project, create a docker image, then pushed the image to a private Azure Registry service.
2. Deploy the image on a slot called `staging` in Azure Web Service.

Here is the `.yaml` file that I am using

```yaml
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'MyPrivateRegistry'
  imageRepository: 'MyPrivateRepositoryName'
  containerRegistry: 'MyPrivateRepositoryName.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  azureSubscription: 'MyPrivateSubscribtionName(5c4b9a4b-private-subscribtion-id-91503531e1a0)'
  appName: 'private_appname'
  resourceGroupName: 'PrivateResourceGroup'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Push and Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: '$(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
  - job: DeployToStaging
    displayName: Deploy To staging
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: succeeded()
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: AzureWebAppContainer@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
        appName: $(appName)
        deployToSlotOrASE: true
        resourceGroupName: $(resourceGroupName)
        slotName: 'staging'
        containers: '$(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)'
```

The projects is built successfully and pushed to the private registry as expected. I can verify that the new image in pushed with a new tagId. However, my container fails to start with the following error

> Image pull failed since Inspect image returned null: MyPrivateRepositoryName.azurecr.io/MyPrivateRepositoryName:151

Here is the suggestion I see

```
Please check the repository name, image name, and container definitions defined by DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME, DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL, and DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD.
```

When I go to the staging slot configuration I see the following and the values are all correct. I copied these values from the "Access keys" section in the Container Registry service after enabling the Admin user

What am I missing here? How can I get the slot to correctly pull the docker image from the contain registry?

[image]

### Updated

Looking more at the logs gives me this error

```
2022-04-01T20:36:21.409Z ERROR - Pull image threw Exception: Input string was not in a correct format.
2022-04-01T20:36:21.411Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: privateregistry.azurecr.io/privateimage:152
2022-04-01T20:36:21.594Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://privateregistry.azurecr.io/v2/privateimage/manifests/152: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}
```

It sounds like something does not have permission to pull the docker image from the repository. Question is what object need to have this permission? Would I add permission to the private repository of would I add it to the Web Service?

Comment: Please, consider read [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60163440/docker-fails-to-pull-the-image-from-within-azure-app-service), I think it could be of help.

Comment: @jccampaneroI did the 5 steps in the answer, expect using managed identity instead of the system identity and did not work.

Answer (score 1):

**Few things you can check if [Enable Admin Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60163440/docker-fails-to-pull-the-image-from-within-azure-app-service) does not work.**

- Is your app service in the same subscription as your ACR? If not, try moving it to the same subscription.
- In Azure Portal -> App Service -> Deployment Center, see if you have conflicting settings. If it's empty, try set up the container registry information here instead of passing in app settings as env variables.
- [image]

**If still having errors**, I recommend you creating another credential to login to ACR instead of using the admin one. (For this, it won't involve system identity or managed identity)

1. [Register a new app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) that will read from ACR
2. In ACR -> Access Control -> give this app ACR PULL permission
3. Replace your app service app setting with the following

- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME = Client Id of the created app
- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD = Client Secret of the created app