# azure app service can't find my endpoints added after first deploy

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, fastapi

I deployed in an azure app service based on a docker image from a private docker hub repository. After configured the instance, i uploaded the app files by FTPS in the /wwwroot folder as required.

In the first moment, it's ok, my API had 1 endpoint and worked fine. After this, i changed the files by FTPS and add one more endpoint in the router, but my when i ran the instance, the new endpoint can't be found.

I looked at the files in the instance and it seems to be fine, that's my route file:

```
from typing import Union

from fastapi import APIRouter
from fastapi import Depends
from fastapi import HTTPException

from ..extensions.database import get_resp_dict
from ..extensions.database import get_sla_dict
from ..extensions.schemas import TaskResponsibleResponse
from ..extensions.schemas import TaskResponsibleSetterSchema
from ..extensions.schemas import TaskSlaResponse
from ..extensions.schemas import TaskSlaSetterSchema
from ..extensions.security import authenticate_request


router = APIRouter(prefix="/flow/contractmanager", tags=["Flows"])


@router.post("/")
def get_task_responsible(
    request: TaskResponsibleSetterSchema,
    resp_dict: dict = Depends(get_resp_dict),
    token: dict = Depends(authenticate_request),
) -> Union[TaskResponsibleResponse, None]:
    """Get the task responsible by directory"""
    try:
        task_responsible = resp_dict[request.directory]
    except KeyError | Exception:
        raise HTTPException(400, detail="Directory not found")

    return TaskResponsibleResponse(directory=request.directory, responsible=task_responsible)


@router.post("/sla")
def set_task_sla(
    request: TaskSlaSetterSchema, sla_dict: dict = Depends(get_sla_dict), token: dict = Depends(authenticate_request)
) -> Union[TaskSlaResponse, None]:
    """Get the task SLA by category"""
    try:
        task_sla = sla_dict[request.category]
    except KeyError | Exception:
        raise HTTPException(400, detail="Directory not found")

    return TaskSlaResponse(category=request.category, sla=task_sla)
```

but when i get the "/docs" endpoint to find swagger, it just doesn't appears there.

I tried to run it locally but it works fine in docker container on my machine.

I just can't figure out what is happening.

Just to know, i'm using a F1 free instance, limited to 60 minutes per day, i don't know if this can't block this kind of stuff

Could you guys help me out?

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app

ENV POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=false
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev gcc

RUN pip install poetry

COPY . .

RUN poetry install --without dev --no-interaction --no-ansi

EXPOSE 8000

RUN chmod +x /app/docker-entrypoint.sh

CMD ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

poetry run uvicorn senior.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

my main file:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from .extensions.settings import config
from .routes.task import router as task_router


def create_app(title: str, description: str, routes: list) -> FastAPI:
    """App factory"""
    app = FastAPI(title=title, description=description)

    for route in routes:
        app.include_router(route)

    app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=config.origins, allow_methods=config.methods)

    return app


app = create_app(config.title, config.description, [task_router])
```

my app service instance settings:
[image]

My problem isn't with the deployment, is with WHAT is deployed.

Despite i added the code, i can't find it in azure app

[image]

BUt when running locally:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple FastAPI application that you can use as a starting point. additional endpoint besides the default `/docs` endpoint for Swagger documentation.

```py
# main.py

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"message": "Hello, World!"}

@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, query_param: str = None):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "query_param": query_param}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

**requirements.txt:**

```
fastapi==0.68.0
uvicorn==0.15.0
```

Below is the Dockerfile which I used for my application.

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev gcc

# Copy the local directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . .

# Install project dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Expose port 8000
EXPOSE 8000

# Specify the command to run on container start
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

- One common reason for the image pull failure is that the container registry credentials are incorrect or expired check this SO [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60163440/docker-fails-to-pull-the-image-from-within-azure-app-service). You can try to update the credentials in the App Service configuration and restart the app.

[image]

Here I choosed the availablity location as **EastUS** and for sample application I choosed public access.

Then I configure ACR to my app service web app as below.

[image]

You should have the same region in both ACR and webapp aslo.

[image]

- Another possible reason is that the app service identity does not have the proper role assignment to access the [container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container). You can use the Azure CLI commands to enable the system-assigned or user-assigned managed identity for the app service and grant it the AcrPull role

Comment: i think you misunderstood me, i updated the question with more information